# Will Bloons Tower Defence 5 run on an iPhone 3GS

Tags: ios, bloons-td-5

When I saw that there was a new Bloons Tower Defense game on the Apple App Store I thought it deserved immediate purchasing, but then I remembered that I had done the same thing with other apps and discovered that I had paid for something that my phone cannot run. I looked through the description of the app and found nothing about device requirements, only operating system ones and that the comments only yielded that it crashes a lot on every device, which is something that is apparently being worked on. Does anyone know if this will work on an iPhone 3GS before I waste my money on it?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up purchasing the game and it works about as well as I could hope. The game worked perfectly for me until about round 76 when the game slowed down considerably, but this happened in bloons TD 4 as well, so I expected this. The game slowed down to the point of about 1 frame per second, but it never crashed. As a side note, the slowing of the game has been partially addressed with the monkey temple which combines various towers together and nearly restored the game to the normal speed.